# PHP - Access JSON Array

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments

I am trying to access a value in my JSON Array. This is my PHP code to get the JSON content:

```
$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$event_json = json_decode($input);
$event = \Stripe\Event::retrieve($event_id);
```

This is the output:

```
Stripe\Event JSON: {
"id": "evt_6WV8LzHBPwRYW4",
"created": 1435683755,
"livemode": false,
"type": "charge.succeeded",
"data": {
"object": {
"id": "ch_6WV8a3Sdj3ihE2",
"object": "charge",
"created": 1435683755,
"livemode": false,
"paid": true,
"status": "succeeded",
"amount": 5000,
"currency": "usd",
"refunded": false,
"source": {
"id": "card_6WV8kV4c36X1Gl",
"object": "card",
"last4": "4242",
"brand": "Visa",
"funding": "credit",
"exp_month": 2,
"exp_year": 2022,
"fingerprint": "QXn7Az3ZTTaLBbhx",
"country": "US",
"name": "oliverbusk@hotmail.com",
"address_line1": null,
"address_line2": null,
"address_city": null,
"address_state": null,
"address_zip": null,
"address_country": null,
"cvc_check": "pass",
"address_line1_check": null,
"address_zip_check": null,
"tokenization_method": null,
"dynamic_last4": null,
"metadata": [],
"customer": "cus_6WV87uyazq5L64"
},
"captured": true,
"balance_transaction": "txn_6WV8Bz6aZSB3tb",
"failure_message": null,
"failure_code": null,
"amount_refunded": 0,
"customer": "cus_6WV87uyazq5L64",
"invoice": null,
"description": null,
"dispute": null,
"metadata": {
"product": "deposit"
},
"statement_descriptor": null,
"fraud_details": [],
"receipt_email": null,
"receipt_number": null,
"shipping": null,
"destination": null,
"application_fee": null,
"refunds": {
"object": "list",
"total_count": 0,
"has_more": false,
"url": "\/v1\/charges\/ch_6WV8a3Sdj3ihE2\/refunds",
"data": []
}
}
},
"object": "event",
"pending_webhooks": 1,
"request": "iar_6WV8y99x1gReuF",
"api_version": "2015-06-15"
}
```

To be specific, I wish to access the `data->metadata->product` value - which in this example is "deposit"

This is how I am trying to access it:

```
$event->data->metadata->product;
```

Although that returns blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is an object property under data: `$event->data->object->metadata->product`.  Do a `print_r()` on `$event ` to see the structure.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Don't know how I could miss that. That's the solution. Do you mind submitting it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `object` property under `data`. Do a `print_r()` on `$event` to see the structure.

Use: `$event->data->object->metadata->product`

You can see in the `print_r()`:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => evt_6WV8LzHBPwRYW4
    .....
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [object] => stdClass Object
                (
                    .....
                    [metadata] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [product] => deposit
                        )
```